# User created functions can't be resolved in VBA immediate window though they show up in intellisense

Tags: excel, functional-programming, vba

I've created a user-defined function in VBA and it doesn't solve in the immediate window nor in a cell. Although I can see the created function, namely `customdate`, in Intellisense, it won't show up in the immediate window. I can, however, get built-in functions going. Please let me know if you need any more details. Unfortunately, I can't upload the image due to a lack of reputation but the code is below. I've also uploaded screenshots on Google Docs.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Function customdate() As String
customdate = Format(Date, "ddd dd mm yyy")
End Function

Function Area(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
Area = x * y
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If your functions are in a Class module, you need to explicitly include the Class in the function call.  That includes UserForms, Worksheets, and Workbooks.  They will also only be available as a UDF if they are in a Module.  For example, if this is in Sheet1...

```
Function customdate() As String
    customdate = Format(Date, "ddd dd mm yyy")
End Function

Function Area(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
    Area = x * y
End Function
```

You need to use this in the immediate window:

```
?Sheet1.customdate
Tue 05 05 15125
```

For `Area`, you also need to pass it parameters:

```
?Sheet1.Area(5, 5)
 25
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response Comintern :) that was helpful. Do you know why can't I find the function in a cell just unlike I can see list of inbuilt functions?

Comment: @NandeshK - Is the code in a Module or a Class?  It has to be in a Module to be used in a cell.